# How to set permissions for a POST request in ModelViewSet's

Tags: permissions, django-rest-framework

How can I write my own permission class for POST requests when using ModelViewSet?

I already tried to write my own permission_classe with no success. Even if my permission class is returning false it is still granting access to the post request

## models.py

```
class Building(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) limit_choices_to=Q(country=2921044) | Q(country=798544), on_delete=models.SET_NULL) #<------------ Eltern Element
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description         = models.TextField(max_length=2000,null=True, blank=True)
    facilities          = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

## views.py

```
class BuildingImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    serializer_class = BuildingImageSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwner,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return     BuildingImage.objects.filter(building__user=self.request.user)
        return None
```

## permissions.py

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("TEST")
        return False
```

## urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'buildingimages', myrest_views.BuildingImageViewSet, base_name="buildingimage")
```

If I I try to upload an image it is working, Why?
My IsOwner permission class is evaluated because I can see the print line with "TEST" in the console.

## MY SOLUTION:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):

    if view.action == 'create':
        building_url    = request.POST.get('building')
        building_path   = urlparse(building_url).path
        building_id     = resolve(building_path).kwargs['pk']
        building        = Building.objects.get(id=building_id)
        return building.user == request.user

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass list of classes, you used `has_object_permission()`, You need to write code inside `has_permission()` method.

```
permission_classes = [<class 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'>]
```

you have to pass class that derive `BasePermission` class

**permission.py**

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

     def has_permission(self, request, view):
         if <CONDITION>:
             return True
         else:
             return False
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right! But I have another problem now. (I edited my question)
How can I check if the ForeignKey is owned by the user? In has_object_permission I did something like that: return obj.building.user == request.user
But in has_permission there is no obj?

Comment: Is building model have user's foreign key? Please don't mix up two questions togather. Ask another question regarding foreign key issue.

Comment: Yes. I added my solution to the topic because I solved it.

Comment: Can you post your building model here ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the first post